# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32event'

Tags: python-3.x

in my Python Script there is an ERROR with the line
import win32events
I still installed the package pypiwin32 (with pip install pypiwin32) but it seems that this is nor the right package.
Does someone know what I need to install to use win32events in Python?

Answer (score 6):

You should install **pywin32** package (not pypiwin32)!!!